# how to input string of numbers as int* using while C++

Tags: c++

The verifier will enter a string of numbers separated by spaces (example: "1 2 45 60 98"). The number of numbers in a string is unknown. You must write each number as a separate element of the array. When compiling, Visual Studio throws an error and reports no exceptions. As i understand, "while" don't stop and continue working.  How can I do this task otherwise?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int* b = new int;
    while (b[i] != '\n')
    {
        cin >> b[i];
        cout << b[i]; \\ just checking
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What error* do you get? Please provide the full error message.

Comment: `b` points to a single `int`, yet you treat it as if it was an array.

Comment: For an array, you need to specify the capacity to the `new` operator:  `int * b = new int [5];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exhibits multiple varieties of undefined behavior. This should be handled with `::std::vector` and `::std::string`. You should largely never be using `new` directly in any code you write.

First, you allocate an `int` but never initialize it. Then you test it to see if it's value is `'\n'` (which happens to be 10), but accessing the integer before it's initialized is undefined behavior.

Next, you read in an integer, and then increment i to 1, then access `b[i]`, which is again undefined behavior because you're reading memory that you've never allocated. You allocated space for one `int`, and you're trying to access a second.

The fact your are confused about why this code doesn't work tells me that you have some really significant misunderstandings about a number of different things.

For example, even without the undefined behavior problems I just mentioned, your loop test would never test the most recently read value, it always tests a value that you haven't yet read.

And also, if you enter a blank line, the read won't even return. That's whitespace, and whitespace is simply skipped over by the iostream library when you ask for an `int`. Even if you were checking the most recently read value in your while loop, you would have to enter `10` to get your program to stop, not a blank line.

My suggestion would be to find a TA to help you. The number of misunderstandings and mistakes in this simple snippet of code is too hard to unwind in a StackOverflow question without simply telling you what the answer is. And this looks a lot like homework. I'm not going to tell you what the answer is.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i understand my mistakes
Will try to correct my code.
Maybe you are right about TA, because i'm only starting learning C++.
But, honestly, i hope i can understand this language by myself using method of making mistakes.

Comment: @MaximKardackow , if possible supplement your education with a few other resources. [Here is a curated list of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Since books ain't cheap and you probably already have some focused on the art of programming, if not on good use of C++, [here is a link to an abbreviated and terse book posted online by the author](https://isocpp.org/tour) that you can fact-check against.

Answer (score 1):

read the entire line as a string.

read each int from that string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream s(line);
    vector<int> v;
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(s), istream_iterator<int>(), back_insert_iterator<vector<int>>(v));

    for (auto i:v) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, nobody should be using `strok` in a C++ program. Using the built in regular expression library would be better. Also, giving the OP the answer to his question isn't helping him.

Comment: there is a strtok_s that is context safe that can be used instead of strtok

Comment: It's not whether or not it's context safe that's the problem. The problem is that it's not really C++. I actually think the C++ standard should just tell people to not use the C standard library at all, except for the functions that are basically thin system call wrappers.

Comment: The variant of `getline` being used here needs extra code to handle potential overflows. `getline` promises the buffer won't be overflowed, but the stream is placed in the fail state to force the programmer to acknowledge and deal with the left-over data. `std::string` and `std::getline` would be a much better choice anywhere `std::vector` would be in use.

Comment: you are right, the proper way would be to use std::getline and put it in a string, and yes, stringstream is a good option. I will update the answer with these details. Thank you